# How to change "sender:" field in the header of Logwatch emails

Tags: linux, postfix, logwatch

I changed MailFrom="" in /usr/share/logwatch/default.conf/logwatch.conf

That altered "From:" in the headers, but "Sender:" is still "root@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.domain"

---

EC2 Linux AMI beta,
Postfix is the mailer

Comment: Changing default mailer to use -> mailer= "sendmail -t -f user@your.domain" helped.

Answer (score 7):

Arrived here via google with the same problem.

Adding the "-f user" option to sendmail in `/usr/share/logwatch/default.conf/logwatch.conf` had no effect.

Turns out logwatch.pl processes `/usr/share/logwatch/dist.conf/logwatch.conf` after `/usr/share/logwatch/default.conf/logwatch.conf`.

Edit or remove the `MailFrom = root` override in `/usr/share/logwatch/dist.conf/logwatch.conf` for it to work.

Comment: Agree with editing /usr/share/logwatch/dist.conf/logwatch.conf.
But also check the script (if any) executed by cron for more overrides.
For Ubuntu (Precise) this is in /etc/cron.daily/00logwatch.
If the package maintainer overwrites these you will need to revisit them.

Answer (score 5):

There are several locations where Logwatch configuration details can be specified, with each one superseding the previous one:

```
/usr/share/logwatch/default.conf/*
/etc/logwatch/conf/dist.conf/*
/etc/logwatch/conf/*
The script / command line arguments
```

It is recommended to change: `/etc/logwatch/conf/logwatch.conf`